# Grab Kanji webpage using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, unicode, character-encoding, special-characters, nokogiri

I would like to grab a kanji table on a Wikipedia page and I have a trouble using Nokogiri with special char.  Here is my script:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

link = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_j%C5%8Dy%C5%8D_kanji'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link))
doc.encoding = 'UTF-8'

d = []
doc.css('.wikitable tr').each do |tr|
  row = []
  tr.css('td').each {|td| row << td.text }
  d << row
end

d.each {|row| row.each {|td| puts td } }
y = YAML.dump(d, STDOUT)
puts y
```

My trouble is that, it returns binary chars (like ã¯ã) rather then kanji characters (like 人).

How can I edit it in order to fix this?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: kanji are not special characters, imho, they are just normal japanese characters.

Comment: @S.Mark they're "special" in the sense that compared to say most of the Latin based language they have HUGE amount of codepage/symbol so in some cases can require more "special" processing than Latin based languages.

But other wise for most part as long as the application can handle Unicode they can be handled about the same as normal text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(link),nil,'UTF-8')
```

Works for me, if your terminal don't support japanese characters, dump it into file.